# Replacement for big array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, data-structures

I have an array of objects with a length of 614 125.
The point is to get an index from a 3 bytes number by getting the modulo 85 of each byte value.

It's a big array, but FAR below the limit allowed, yet it's incredibly slow, despite having a direct index access (I'm actually never iterating through the array).

The problem is that I'm using hashed values (3 bytes) that I cannot know in advance, so I can't predict the value nor make it smaller. My idea seemed clever but the array is so big that it makes my game twice slower.

Is there an alternative to this kind of situation? Note that I have tried a HashMap but it is even slower, because my hash values are too far apart.

I'm trying to figure out a way to not allocate a huge array from the start but rather dynamically add new objects. Using my Node object with a "next" and "previous" would solve the problem and would make sorting very fast, but I can't figure a way to find my hash without an O(N/2) order, which is too long (I want O(1)).

Here is the code if it's of any use:

### HashMap

```
public class HashMap {
    public static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 614125;
    // This value represents 255/3 (max byte value)=> hash is 3 bytes long:
    // First byte%85 gives us the first index, same for second and third.
    private static final int MODULO = 85;
    private static final int FIRST_MULTIPLIER = 7225;
    private static final int SECOND_MULTIPLIER = 85;

    private Node[] mHashMap;
    private int index1, index2, index3;

    public HashMap() {
        mHashMap = new Node[ARRAY_SIZE];
    }

    public void put(int hash, int value) {
        index1 = (hash & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        index2 = ((hash >> 8) & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        index3 = ((hash >> 16) & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        int index = index1 * FIRST_MULTIPLIER + index2 * SECOND_MULTIPLIER + index3;
        Node node = mHashMap[index];
        if (node == null) {
            mHashMap[index] = new Node(value);
        } else {
            node.addValue(value);
        }
    }

    public Node get(int hash) {
        index1 = (hash & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        index2 = ((hash >> 8) & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        index3 = ((hash >> 16) & 0xFF) % MODULO;
        int index = index1 * FIRST_MULTIPLIER + index2 * SECOND_MULTIPLIER + index3;
        return mHashMap[index];
    }
}
```

### Node

```
public class Node {
    private Node mNext;
    private int mValue;

    public Node(int value) {
        mValue = value;
        mNext = null;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        mNext = next;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return mNext != null;
    }

    public Node next() {
        return mNext;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void addValue(int value) {
        mValue += value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code? Which method slows you down? You get method runs in O(1) so it doesn't look like it would be a bottleneck...

Comment: Just a tip: don't ever name classes you wrote yourself identically to classes in the standard Java library: you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: @assylias yes, it's only due to the array size. executing exactly the same code with an array of say 85 (thus only using index1) is very fast. but as soon as the size grows, it gets incredibly slow

Comment: Large arrays are not inherently slow.  Accessing an array element is almost instantaneous regardless of how big the index is.  You don't have any code that steps through all elements of the array.  A big array can cause slowness if it's so big that it forces a lot of memory swapping, but I don't think array will be big enough to cause a problem unless you're running on a very old computer with very limited memory.  I suspect your performance issues are elsewhere.

Comment: @ajb i can try to look again but i'm pretty sure it comes from the size alone, because reducing the size while doing exactly the same amount of computations returns a good speed.

Comment: @zuokuok your code should not be slower with larger arrays. The problem is probably somewhere else (possibly another class). Profile your code and check time spent on GC.

Comment: @assylias the problem comes from the "put" method (obviously), which accesses the array a couple million times in a second. Without using "put", my program takes 1s to finish. Using "put", it takes 1.9s to finish. But if I change the array size to 85 while using "put" (still millions of times), it takes also 1s to finish.

Comment: Your put method creates new `Node` objects which may slow it down.

Comment: @Bubletan ok I was actually just trying that as you replied, and it is indeed the problem... god I'm tired. I didn't even think about this earlier.

Comment: @zuokuok Have you tried using a simple `int` array? It takes some memory but should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out a way to not allocate a huge array from the start but rather dynamically add new objects.

Why? IIUYC you don't need to minimize memory consumption. Using less memory may lead to speed gains, but I don't think it applies here.

The culprit is most probably your very slow hash computation. Performing `%` multiple times is very costly and not needed here. If you want to map an `int` to an array index, you can do it using a single modulo (good when the array size is a prime) or *no slow operation at all* (when the array size is a power of two).

I'd suggest something like

```
private static final int LOG_ARRAY_SIZE = 19;
private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 1 << LOG_ARRAY_SIZE;

private int toIndex(int x) {
    return (x * 0xcc9e2d51) >>> (32-LOG_ARRAY_SIZE);
}

public void put(int hash, int value) {
    index = toIndex(hash);
    Node node = mHashMap[index];
    if (node == null) {
        mHashMap[index] = new Node(value);
    } else {
        node.addValue(value);
    }
}

public Node get(int hash) {
    index = toIndex(hash);
    return mHashMap[index];
}
```